# Tip box for wordpress in post content

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I would like to add some tip boxes to my worpress blog posts. 3 boxes will be placed in the content and I want to place them dinamically.

**Top positions:**

The first box - 30%

The second box - 60%

The third box - 90%

I will align them to left and right with the "float" attribute. But I can not find any html tag that will place the boxes to the needed positions. I want to add the codes of the boxes to the end of the post. All the posts will have different length and I don't want to place every box code manually. The post text should sorround the boxes.

I hope you can understand my problem. THX!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a plugin would work better for this.  There are a lot of them out there, but I used one I liked here and made a short video on how it's used.  http://wordpresswidget.net/use-this-wordpress-tool-tip-hover-widget-for-your-site/

This one also looks like it would work well http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-tooltips/

I demoed it here for you: http://wordpresswidget.net/wordpress-tool-tips/

From what I understand of your question one of these should do it.  I'm sure you could customize and style the plugin too.

Comment: These plugins are useful and thanks for your efforts but I need something that doesn't require any action, just place the code in the content.

Comment: alright, in Wordpress in post code is limited to just HTML in my understanding.  a plugin might be your best option. :) I'll look around for anything else I can find though.

Comment: Thanks. It will be good to place some short codes instead the box codes. Then replace them to the box codes. Some good plugins available for this. But the problem is still the same. To place that codes to the right position.

Comment: I hope this will helps me: http://omninoggin.com/wordpress-posts/how-to-add-ads-inside-your-post-content/ I will check it tomorrow.